# How do I set the left margin for a html paragraph shown in a Jasperreports TextField

Tags: html, jasper-reports

I am making a subreport using Jaspersoft Studio 6.2.1. The subreport only contains a `TextField` defined as follows:

```
<band height="105">
    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
        <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="505" height="47" uuid="03b4eae9-6dd0-4fdb-b2c5-5d8a5ba3b71d"/>
        <textElement textAlignment="Justified" markup="html">
            <font fontName="Verdana" size="10"/>
            <paragraph lineSpacing="1_1_2" leftIndent="0" spacingAfter="250"/>
        </textElement>
        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Some text"]]></textFieldExpression>
    </textField>
</band>
```

It works properly, making the PDF view with whatever content I put. Although, it can render html tags like <b>, <ul> or <u>, it doesn't render the html paragrahp (<p>) tag as it should when I set a style for it. Below, there are two images showing what I'm trying to achive and the end result.

[image]

[image]

As can be seen, both paragraphs are shown without any margin. I know I can set a style for all paragraphs inside the textField element, but  is there any way to achieve that any paragraph has its own style according to its style attribute?

Answer (score 0):

What you are experiencing has to do with the fact that, internally, JasperReports uses just a `javax.swing.JEditorPane` for processing HTML text that, unfortunately, supports only HTML 3.2 even in more recent Java versions.

So you should not rely on inline styling when writing HTML markup.

Comment: Thank your for your answer. Any idea of how can I achive what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Other than separate each paragraph into its own element, nothing else comes to mind.

Comment: I had thought about that, but it's not an option. Thanks again.

Comment: A more complex approach would be to write your custom MarkupProcessor and replace the default one with a jasperreports property. The default is: `net.sf.jasperreports.markup.processor.factory.html=net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JEditorPaneMarkupProcessor.HtmlFactory`